# How can I use SonarQube to scan an ASPNET Core 1.1 project?

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, sonarqube

I have my Mac setup with Jenkins and SonarQube and Docker to test automation. I also have the same setup on my Windows VM using VMWare and all the windows variants as well. My .NET application compiles well and I can run SonarQube after pulling from GitHub and running MSBuild.exe against it fine. But how can I do a similar process with the 'dotnet restore', 'dotnet publish' on my Mac with the .NET Open Source projects like ASPNET Core 1.1? I have not seen how to setup SonarQube to scan the ASPNET Core 1.1 or the DotNet Core 1.1 projects with any prebuild, build, postbuild steps from within Jenkins. Is there support for the ASPNET Core yet in SonarQube? Do I need a patch or to run a certain commandline group of scripts to do the same thing natively on my Mac? Any help is appreciated. I have searched for a few hours and have found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The support of .NET Core projects is not yet available in the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild. We are currently working on it and it should be available within the upcoming 2 weeks.

Feel free to watch [SONARMSBRU-167](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-167) to follow the status.

Comment: is that for all versions? Whether running SonarQube on Windows or Mac OS X or Linux? My specific question was on Mac but curious if across all of the OS variants that the .NET Core / ASPNET Core apps work.

Comment: For the moment, this will only work on Windows because we only support build through MSBuild (12, 14 and soon 15). Being able to run an analysis on other platforms (macOS or Linux) will come in the future.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam Is this fix available now? I have asp.net core .xproj projects and not using msbuild to build. Do I need to keep some pointers in mind?

Comment: This thread is often found when searching for "dotnet core sonarqube", the issue summary doesnt link to annoucement or documentation page, if such page exists. Can you update answer and link to https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild ?